# rebase a commit without merging it into the base commit (just move it next to a specific commit on another branch)

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

i had a main branch that looked like this at some point in the history.

```
A <-- B <-- C <-- D  (main)
```

at this time i squashed **C** into the **D** using interactive rebase and got commit **C'**. on commit **C'** i created **v1** branch and while i was on **main** branch i made another commit (**E**). so the repository now looks like this:

```
A <-- B <-- C' <-- E (main)
           (v1)
```

again i squashed **C'** into **E** and got **C"**.

```
A <-- B <-- C'(v1)
      ⇡__ C"(main)
```

after that i made another commit **F** and Squashed **C"** into it and got **C"'**. so at the current time my repository looks like this:

```
A <-- B <-- C'(v1)
      ⇡__ C"'(main)
```

now i want to rebase commit **C"'** on top of **C'** but without having to merge their differences from their common parent **B**. in other words i want to move **C"'** on top of **C'** as if i directly made all the changes to **C'** and after committing those changes i got **C"'**

Comment: So you want to keep the _snapshot_ of your project of C''', but pretend it happened after C'?

Comment: @knittl
 that's exactly what i want

Comment: In that case my answer should contain the relevant Git commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to:

```
git checkout main # check out branch main (commit C''')
git reset --soft v1 # move HEAD to v1 (commit C'), but keep all files and keep index
git commit -C "C'''" # commit index with commit message of commit C''' (previous tip of "main")
```

Comment: one thing i don't get about your answer is that at the last stage HEAD is already on main branch and working directory and index is clean because i committed staged changes in previous step. so how the second line `git reset --soft v1` keeps index when it's already clean

Comment: i just looked through the git documentation on reset and figured that i had a wrong idea about git cleaning working directory and index after each commit (because of this misleading  massage git shows by running `git status` after committing changes: _nothing to commit, working tree clean_ )

Comment: @MohamadBakhtiari it keeps the index identical to the commit pointed to by `main` (i.e. HEAD). When you move `HEAD`, the index and the head commit no longer match and a new commit can/will be created.